# moment vs date-fns locale date formats

Tags: momentjs, date-fns

I'm evaluating DateFns and Moment in the context of our app, and found what appears to be an important omission in DateFns.

In Moment, locale support allows you to format locale-correct representations of a date or time. For instance, the date formats "LL" and "L" will produce the following for the English locale:

```
November 27, 2017
11/27/2017
```

And the following for the Spanish locale:

```
27 de noviembre de 2017
27/11/2017
```

Note in particular that in the second example, the month comes before the day in English, whereas the day comes before the month in Spanish. That's exactly the kind of thing you want locale code to handle for you. This is how locales work in almost all datetime libraries (C++, C#, Java, Python, etc.)

In the DateFns, there doesn't appear to be a [format option for locale-correct long date, short date, time, etc.](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format).  The example they give for using a locale requires that you pass it the locale-specific format string:

```
// Represent 2 July 2014 in Esperanto:
var eoLocale = require('date-fns/locale/eo')
var result = format(
  new Date(2014, 6, 2),
  'Do [de] MMMM YYYY',
  {locale: eoLocale}
)
```

In other words, I need to know the date/time format for every locale I support, which defeats the purpose of having locale support in the first place.]

I can use Javascript's toLocaleString, but then my app it managing locale two different ways.

Is there some way of printing out, say, a "short date" for a particular locale without me telling DateFns what the format for that locale is?

Comment: It is supposed to be available in `date-fns@2.0.0` (not released yet, alpha-7 version in progress) https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.7/docs/format

Comment: Maybe you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat as an alternative.

Answer (score 13):

I use the esm version of date-fns and you can use the same type of formats that moment uses :

```
import { format } from 'date-fns/esm'
import { enUS, fr } from 'date-fns/esm/locale'
```

I'll store the locales in an object :

```
this.dateLocales = { fr: fr, en: enUS }
```

and use these formats :

```
LT: 'h:mm aa',
LTS: 'h:mm:ss aa',
L: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
LL: 'MMMM D YYYY',
LLL: 'MMMM D YYYY h:mm aa',
LLLL: 'dddd, MMMM D YYYY h:mm aa'
```

So you can do :

```
format(
  new Date(2014, 6, 2),
  'LL',
  {locale: this.dateLocales.fr}
)
```

Those formats are localised

Comment: Hey @Lakston, thanks for the tip, your answer seems to use a string and not a constant, is that in purpose? Could you clarify how the different formats are defined?

Comment: You are right I forgot to specify that I have an object to store the locales, I'm not passing a string but a reference to my import, I'll update my answer, if it's not clear enough don't hesitate to ask for more infos.

Comment: I was just curious, but I think this answer can still be helpful to some people until `date-fns@2.0.0` is released :)

Comment: My answer works with the `2.0.0` alpha so you won't have to change any, or very little, code when they officially release a RC ;)

Answer (score 7):

As of 2021, using currently latest version of date-fns (v2.23.0), you can achieve what you want by using the 'P' format.

See: https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format

For example, given that today is 2021-08-27 (ISO date):

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import ptBrLocale from 'date-fns/locale/pt-BR';
import enUsLocale from 'date-fns/locale/en-US';

console.log(format(new Date(), 'P', { locale: ptBrLocale }));
console.log(format(new Date(), 'P', { locale: enUsLocale }));
```

Outputs will be:

```
27/08/2021
08/27/2021
```