# Multiple locale support with date-fns

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

Using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) in version `2.0.0-alpha.11`, I trying to get the same behavior as the following *momentjs* calls:

```
moment().format('LL');   // July 26, 2018
moment().format('LLL');  // July 26, 2018 4:59 PM
```

What I tried is the following:

```
import format from 'date-fns/esm/format';
const formattedDate = format(new Date(2018, 6, 26, 16, 59, 0), 'LL');
```

In that case `formattedDate` returns the month number `07`.

In the source code for locales, there are [definitions for short, medium, long and full format](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/fr/_lib/formatLong/index.js). Is there no ways to get these definitions with the `format` functions based on the current locale?

I have looked at the [documentation](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started) and at the [release notes](https://gist.github.com/kossnocorp/a307a464760b405bb78ef5020a4ab136) but I cannot find a way.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47271803/4131048), maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried but still get the month number with `LL` syntax, even if a locale is passed as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking deeper at the source code, I found a solution:

```
moment().format('LL');  ==> format(new Date(), 'PP');
moment().format('LLL'); ==> format(new Date(), 'PPp');
```

The output is not strictly equivalent to *momentjs* but close enough in my case.